# In Firebase is it possible to have separate authentication but use same Cloud Firestore database?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I have an app in which there are two types of users which share database with each other. e.g. One type of user is students and other is teacher. The logic is as follows : a student can also be a teacher and a teacher can also be a student and both have to share a common database with each other for various purposes. But at signup phase, there are different information for both the cases which is needed to be entered.

Currently what happens is if a user signs up as a student then using the same id he is able to signin as a teacher which should not happen, i.e. I need different authentication for both, is it possible to implement it in firebase, flutter?

Comment: You can store additional information about the user in Firebase Auth, so if you're using Firestore to store the information about the user, you could store there the role of the user and then permit/forbidden access to your app by that role.

Comment: If I assign role, would they be able to signup again and take up another role too... eg, if I create a teacher and signin then would the teacher be able to signup as student too with the same mail id?

Comment: You'll share the Firebase Auth and Firestore, and have the role assigned to the user in Firestore. Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/role-based-access

Comment: @SantiBarbat There is no option for storing additional user info in Firebase Auth. It's limited to displayName, photoUrl, email and phoneNumber. See the API [FIRUser](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebaseauth/api/reference/Protocols/FIRUserInfo.html). That means you cannot assign a role and store it in that fashion. The link provided for role-based access is what you should look at. OP - you're going to need two different Firebase accounts if a single person can be both student and teacher.

Comment: @Jay, spelling mistake, you CAN NOT store additional information in Firebase Auth, however, if you read the full answer I'll know that I'm suggesting to use Firestore to store additional information.

Comment: @SantiBarbat Yep - just wanted to clarify that point and I also recommended the link you provided. Oh, *cannot* is a contraction of can and not. *Both the one-word form cannot and the two-word form can not are acceptable, but cannot is more common (in the Oxford English Corpus, three times as common). The two-word form is better only in a construction in which not is part of a set phrase, such as ‘not only … but (also)’:*